# crop image and paste in same coords as from source

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, python-imaging-library, object-detection

I am able to detect the person and able to find the coordinates of the person and then i can crop the image. but i want to keep the person and remove all the background/ make it white background / copy the cropped image and paste it in another file in the same coordinates as obtained from the source.
[image]

This is my required image:

[image]

Comment: Ok, are you actually using OpenCV or PIL, as you have tagged both. What code do you have so far? What are the coordinates you want - what format are they in?

Comment: I am using object detection and detecting the person and its bounding rectangle coordinates and from that coordinates i am using PIL and cropping the image. My objective is to crop the person and place it in the same coordinate without anything in the background.

Comment: So, are you using OpenCV and PIL? If so, why are you using both? What format do you have the crop coordinates in and what are they for the above image?

Comment: I'm using opencv for object detection purpose and im getting (x, y, z, w) coordinate which I'm using to crop the image. But i want to paste the same image in a white background in the same coordinate from it's parent picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make a white background image using height and width of input image.
2. Place the cropped image into white background image according to the coordinates.

[image: img1]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('img.png')
person = image[110:532, 250:516] # persons coordinates

h, w, c = image.shape

white_background = np.zeros([h, w, 3])
for y in range(h):
    for x in range(w):
        white_background[y,x] = [255,255,255] # fill with white pixels

white_background[110:532, 250:516] = person  # paste the image into background image

cv2.imwrite('resized_centered.png', white_background)
```

Result:
[image: img2]